# Flutter release version not showing page correctly

Tags: android, flutter

i'm trying to build a release version of my flutter app using the cmd `flutter build apk`, the problem is that one page does not show any content. In the debug version it all works fine, but in the release version that page does not work properly.

The 2 images below show the output for the 2 versions.

**Debug version:**

[image]

**Release version:**

[image]

Code of the page in which the bug occurs:

```
class ProductListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ProductListPage(
      {Key? key,
      Title? title,
      required this.subCatId,
      required this.subCatName})
      : super(key: key);
  final String title = '';
  static const String page_id = 'Product List';
  int subCatId;
  String subCatName;

  @override
  State<ProductListPage> createState() => _ProductListPageState();
}

class _ProductListPageState extends State<ProductListPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: style.appColor),
        title: Text(widget.subCatName),
        centerTitle: false,
        titleTextStyle: style.pageTitle(),
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.share_outlined))
        ],
      ),
      body:
          _buildBody(), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              decoration: style.bottomBorder(),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
                    label: Text('Filter'),
                    style: simpleButton(),
                  )),
                  Expanded(
                      child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Icon(Icons.sort_outlined),
                    label: Text('Sort'),
                    style: simpleButton(),
                  )),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            GetBuilder<ProductsController>(builder: (prodsBySub) {
              Get.find<ProductsController>()
                  .getProductsBySubCategory(widget.subCatId);
              return GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                childAspectRatio: 70 / 100,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                children: List.generate(
                    prodsBySub.productsListBySubCategory.length, (index) {
                  return _buildSingleProduct(
                      index,
                      ProductModel.fromJson(
                          prodsBySub.productsListBySubCategory[index]));
                }),
              );
            })
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSingleProduct(int position, ProductModel product) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        Get.toNamed(RouteHelper.getProduct(position, product.id));
      },
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        decoration: style.shadowContainer(),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 140,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/images/mango.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.contain)),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            Text(
              product.title,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'medium'),
            ),
            Text(
              '50g/pack',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                    child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6, vertical: 1),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                      decoration: style.offContainer(),
                      child: Text('10%', style: style.offLabel()),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${product.price} €',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'medium'),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
                Container(
                  height: 30,
                  width: 30,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
                      color: style.appColor),
                  child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  simpleButton() {
    return ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        onPrimary: Colors.grey,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
        elevation: 0,
        primary: Colors.transparent);
  }
}
```

I have tried some solutions found on the internet like adding Internet permission for the APIs, or editing the build.gradle file. None of these solutions worked for me. I would love to get some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: The usual red screen error in Flutter while debugging shows itself as a grey screen in the release version. To find the exact reason, code samples are needed.

Comment: I think the app is crashing on this page so use "firebase_crashlytics" to track your app crash reports.

Comment: @AbhinavAgrawal but the debug version does not show any errors! I will add code of that page though!

Comment: @TejasPatel I'm not using firebase at all by the way, I'm using my own backend developed with node.js, should I still use the firebase_crashlytics to track my app crash reports?

Comment: Yes, Firebase Crashlytics is helping to track crash reports when the app is in release mode.

Comment: @FedyBelaid Debug version also show the error but it is warning there. You can run app in release mode with  flutter run --release and check the app issues

Comment: Hi, I've finally solved the problem using flutter run --release which showed me where the error is. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

just add expanded around the gridview and everything is work

Answer (score 1):

Solved it thanks to @Amanpreet Kaur's comment, actually I used flutter run --release and it showed me where the error was located, fixed it and it's all good now!